# SQL 2016 puede aceptar como parámetro una lista de ints?

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando con *C# MVC*. Dispongo de una `list<int>` *ListaDeCategorias*

Actualmente poseo un *Store Procedure* que inserta toda la información relacionada a un artículo. En el formulario de *Alta de Articulo*, existe la posibilidad de marcar diferentes categorías.

Te imaginarás que tengo entonces un *Id* de *Articulo* y una lista de *Ids* de *Categorías*.

Mi posible solución es, crear un `foreach`(Cada Id en ListaCategorias) y pasar un único parámetro `INT` a un `SP` que inserte:

```
Id_ART_1 / Id_Cat_1
Id_ART_1 / Id_Cat_2
```

Pero antes de llegar a eso, quisiera saber si es posible directamente pasar como parámetro mi `List<int>` y recibirlo en el `SP` para manejarlo directamente allí dentro.

Esto ahorraría crear un nuevo `SP` para insertar categorías por separado en vez de insertar todo en un único `SP` (Insertar Articulo).

Comment: echa un vistazo a esto select field from table where id in (id1, id2,...);

Comment: Ojo que pudiera terminar cerrada, trata de que sea más específica s problemas concretos de programación a resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A como está, la pregunta puede ser cerrada con rapidez. No es tan específico lo que preguntas y no nos muestras qué has intentado/dónde fallaste.

Dicho esto, una forma de realizar lo que tú quieres, es utilizando un Table Valued Parameter.

Primero, declaras el tipo donde recibirás la lista

```
 CREATE TYPE ListaCategoria(CatId INT);
```

Y en el procedimiento almacenado lo utilizas como parámetro.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GuardarInformacionArticulo
    ( @nombreArticulo varchar(100) ,@descripcionArticulo varchar(100), 
     @Categorias ListaCategoria READONLY)

  as
  -- Lo que sea que haga tu procedimiento. @Categorias contiene la lista
  -- que viene desde c#
```

**EDIT**

Para agregar un poco a la respuesta: Si estás utilizando SqlClient, puedes agregar el parámetro de esta manera:

```
var parametroLista = new SqlParameter("@descripcionArticulo", SqlDbType.Structured);
parametroLista.TypeName = "dbo.ListaCategoria"; //Nombre del Tipo en SQLServer
parametroLista.Value = lista; //Lista de enteros
```

Luego haces el executeQuery de la conexión y verificas la inserción en la bd. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la función `STRING_SPLIT` [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Al procedimiento le pasas el Id_ART y un string compuesto de por tus Id_Cat separados por un asterisco (*). Por ejemplo "1*4*8".

En el procedimiento, utilizando STRING_SPLIT obtienes los Id_Cat individuales, haciendo

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Id_Cat, '*');
```

Obteniendo

```
value
1
4
8
```

Otra opción, más elegante sería creando un [tipo propio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (los puedes ver en SMSS en la rama de Programación --> Tipos) de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TYPE Categorias AS TABLE ( Id_Cat INT );
```

y utilizándolo como parámetro dentro del procedimiento.